# Selecting rows with multiple condition across rows

Tags: sql, select, concatenation, where-clause

I have a table like:

```
MovieID PersonID
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       6
2       1 
etc.
```

How can I select all movie IDs (distinct) where people with personIDs 1 and 2 have been in simultaneously?

I've tried something like:

```
(SELECT movie_id
 FROM stars
 WHERE person_id = (SELECT XXX)
 AND person_id = (SELECT XXX)
)
```

but apparently it doesn't work since each row has only 1 person_id.

Answer (score 1):

I would just use aggregation:

```
select t.movie_id
from t
where t.person_id in (1, 2)
group by t.movie_id
having count(*) = 2;
```

Comment: I don't have 1 and 2 hardcoded (it's just for an example), so I'd need to select them later. How do I go about it then? It doesn't allow me to write `IN(SELECT id FROM people WHERE..., SELECT id FROM people WHERE...)` with the comma

Comment: @Sabie . . . You have to pass them into the query somehow.  Your question suggests they are constants.  You might want to ask a *new* question with a better explanation of how they are chosen.

Comment: They are chosen based on subsequent condition (in particular, based on name). I just showed it here for simplicity, but they should not be hardcoded.

Comment: @Sabie . . . Ask *new* question with a better description of how the values are chosen.  This question has hard-coded values and this answers the question you have asked.